# Mysql calculate Timediff on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, time, calculated-columns

When I add a row to my table I automatically get current time for "created_at" and "updated_at". So whenever I use update query I'm getting the current time for "updated_at" then I manually calculate the time difference between "created_at" and "updated_at" by using `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(updated_at, created_at)) from abc`
command.

Now I wonder is it possible to create a table which can automatically calculates the time difference in seconds and write it in to another column called "timediff" like adding something `timediff ON UPDATE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(updated_at, created_at))`

I've tried something like below but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE abc (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        pieces INT(6), 
        created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW(),
        timediff ON UPDATE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(updated_at, created_at)) -- that's the issue
        )
```

I don't want to mess with triggers or something complex, I'm looking for the most efficient and easy way to sort it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the mysql manual  ...

> A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table,
>   and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. Some
>   uses for triggers are to perform checks of values to be inserted into
>   a table or to perform calculations on values involved in an update.

So, a trigger is intended for precisely the situation you describe. [Full info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html)

Comment: I don't need definition of the trigger.